# Check if condition is satisfied for all related records

Tags: apex, soql

I'm writing a scheduled apex class and I would like to write a code to accomplish this:

check each account in the org and if an account **has all** opportunities with stage=”Cancelled” then set the checkbox named control =true on the account object.

For me it's difficult to check ****if all**** the opportunities have the stage ="Cancelled".

Please could you help me?

Thanks in advantage for any advice.

BR.

Answer (score 1):

you will need trigger  on opportunity insert ,update and delete just to go back and update the parent Account if unchecked and opportunity has stage cancelled .Delete will be tricky .In delete you will examine if there are opportunities linked to account has stage as cancelled .

Update on how to write query for delete case

```
 public class deletetriggerhelper{

  public static void deletetrigger(List<opportunity> newdeleterecords){

   for(opportunity opp:newdeleterecords){
      setaccIds.add(opp.AccountId);
  }

 for(opportunity opp:[Select Id,AccountId,stage from opportunity where stage='Cancelled' from opportunity and AccountId in:setaccIds]){

//Use the utility class to segregrate parent Account Id and opportunity.The utility github link is below

  //https://gist.github.com/msrivastav13/6044144

//check and update Account thats not key in collected map

    }

    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks Mohith but i have to run this code for all the accounts in the or. I haven't triggers. Your solution will be good just for new created accounts and opportunties .I don't know how to write the soql query to know if all the opportunities respects the conditions.

Comment: ok for already records in system just use same trigger logic in batch .I am updating my answer with query on how to write